# What features/model to use for data with Hysteresis?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, sensors

I have made a pressure sensor that when graphing Conductance vs Pressure (disregard the actual values in graph), has the following behaviors:

1. First pressed it has one trendline
2. Afterwards when decreasing pressure it shows hysteresis
3. New trendline when increasing pressure.
4. All new cycles of increase/decrease pressure follow (more or less) the lines of 2 and 3.

[image]

Usually we fit the data with a linear equation. But was wondering if it made sense to use ML to fit the data, feeding in the derivative as an additional feature (thinking of linear regression).

The end goal is to use **Conductivity (feature) to predict Pressure (label)** , reducing the error by accounting for the hysteresis.

What features should I Use?  What model is best?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't know anything about the topic, but based on the graph it seems that there can be several different values of pressure for a single value of conductivity, right? In this case I don't see how predicting pressure from conductivty alone would work. However maybe it's possible to add some features, for instance maybe time.

Comment: thanks @Erwan, my idea is the following: When pressure is increasing it follows line 3, when pressure is decreasing it follows line 2. I can tell if Pressure is increasing or decreasing by calculating the derivative. So basically if you have timeseries data and continuous measurements of the sensor, you can tell if pressure is increasing or decreasing and thus decide on what line (2 or 3) to be on